# How to connect to multiple member accounts from master account in AWS using cmd line;

Tags: amazon-web-services, organization

I am using AWS organization  and want to run ( say **aws s3 ls)** for every member account.
How can do this from the command line of the master account . I can use Cloud9 if it helps.

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Every API call make to AWS is done with a single set of credentials. Those credentials can only access one AWS Account. (You can use those credentials to *Assume a role* in a different account, but that simply returns a new set of temporary credentials that you can use to make an API call on the other account.)

Thus, it is not possible to retrieve information from multiple AWS Accounts with a single API call.

You would need to write a program that would loop through each account, making an API call to that account. Each call would need to be done with credentials specific to the desired account.

Comment: I understand that it has to be a loop. How do I get the credentials ? Is it possible to assume the role which has already been created for permission set. If yes, do have a starters script ?

Comment: You should either have an IAM User in each account, and then just use the associated credentials as you access each account, or you would need an IAM Role in each account, and call `AssumeRole()` for each account. For some code examples, see: [Configure a Lambda function to assume a role from another account](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/) (does not need to be done from Lambda).